# VBA insertAdjacentHTML , stripping tags

Tags: vba, dom

I am processing some HTML in VBA and want to inject a  element to the  tag.

```
 oElement.insertAdjacentHTML "beforeEnd", "<base>HELLO</base>"
```

If I inspect the `oElement.OuterHTML` all that is added is `HELLO`

```
...<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css/default.css">HELLO</HEAD>...
```

If I try adding li tags , it works as expected.

```
oElement.insertAdjacentHTML "beforeEnd", "<li>HELLO</li>"
```

Result

```
....<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css/default.css">HELLO <LI>HELLO</LI> </HEAD>...
```

I've tried using just `<base />` or `<base href="blah blah` , nothing get's added. Am I missing some key piece of knowledge about `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IHTMLDOMNode` interface for head object (don't know why, but it works). Create a "BASE" element, set attribute for `href` and finally add it to a head using `appendChild`.

Comment: An example would have really helped with this, at least for me.